# Junit 5 looking for actual environmental configuration to run the test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, junit5

My project is using `spring-boot`, `sping-data-jpa`, `spring-data-rest`, `hibernate`

I have updated to `spring boot 2.3.1`.

My previous test cases are on `Junit 4`, I am migrating to `Junit 5`.

When I run my test case with junit 5 it is looking for actual environmental configurations like `datasource`, `hibernate:dialect` with Junit 4, it was not looking for it.

Please find Junit 4 and Junit 5 test class for comparison

**Junit 4 Test**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.Sp
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceTest myServiceTest;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

       MyData myData = new MyData();
       myData.setName("testName");
       myData.setNumber()
    
       Mockito.when(myRepository.findMyDataByNameAndNumber(
                Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(myData));
    }
    
    @Test
    void getMyData(){
        myServiceTest.getDataByNameAndNumber("testName", "10101010")
        
        Mockito.verify(myRepository, times(1))
                .findMyDataByNameAndNumber(Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010"));
    }
}
```

**Junit 5 Test**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceTest myServiceTest;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

       MyData myData = new MyData();
       myData.setName("testName");
       myData.setNumber()
    
       Mockito.when(myRepository.findMyDataByNameAndNumber(
                Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(myData));
    }
    
    @Test
    void getMyData(){
        myServiceTest.getDataByNameAndNumber("testName", "10101010")
        
        Mockito.verify(myRepository, times(1))
                .findMyDataByNameAndNumber(Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010"));
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development

---
spring:
  profiles: development
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 

---
spring:
  profiles: unit-test
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:TEST;MODE=Oracle;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TEST
    platform: h2
    continue-on-error: true
```

I am really not sure what I missed in the migration?

***Error log***

```
INFO  [2020-08-04T19:44:04.082+0530] context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper ||${fallback:user}|Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.service.MyServiceTest], using SpringBootContextLoader|${fallback:correlation||${fallback:origin}|${sys:instanceName}| -o
INFO  [2020-08-04T19:44:04.105+0530] support.AbstractContextLoader ||${fallback:user}|Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.service.MyServiceTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.|${fallback:correlation}||${fallback:origin}|${sys:instanceName}| -o
INFO  [2020-08-04T19:44:04.107+0530] support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils ||${fallback:user}|Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.service.MyServiceTest]: MyServiceTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.|${fallback:correlation}||${fallback:origin}|${sys:instanceName}| -o
INFO  [2020-08-04T19:44:04.655+0530] context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper ||${fallback:user}|Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.MyApplication for test class

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 81 more
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 81 more
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primaryEM' defined in class path resource [com/configuration/PrimaryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.2.jar:5.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[.cp/:?]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[.cp/:?]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) [.cp/:?]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) [.cp/:?]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) [.cp/:?]
```

Comment: Maybe `@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")`?

Comment: Not strictly related but if you are mocking the repository you don't need `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: I have tried that one, but still getting the same issue

Comment: `with junit 5 it is looking for actual environmental`. What makes you think that? Any errors?

Comment: can you please share any exception trace?

Comment: I have added the Error Logs above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly looking at your code you are injecting the mocks in to the test class rather than the actual service. Is this how your actual test looks or have you just copied this in so as to not share your actual code?

```
@InjectMocks
private MyServiceTest myServiceTest;
```

Secondly this is a unit test so remove the @SpringBootTest annotation. It is adding unnecessary overhead and is probably causing the error through lack of configuration for code you are not actually testing having mocked the repository anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you you please check if you don't enable any profile in your application.yaml if present in your test resource folder like below :- 
**spring:
profiles:
active: local**

Also can you share the snapshot of your project folder.

Comment: @SSK could you please share the snapshot of your project folder

Comment: I have tried above but not getting the same error as mentioned

Comment: can share your application.yaml file present in test folder ?

Comment: I have shared my .yml file above

Comment: Can you please remove development profile related property and run your test?  spring:
  profiles.active: development
---
spring:
  profiles: development

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, so sharing the answer.

We don't need `@SpringBootTest` and `@ActiveProfiles("unit-test")` on the test class now.
It is working as expected and not calling the actual environmental configuration to run the test. Tests are also super fast as previously.

```
mport org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceTest myServiceTest;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

       MyData myData = new MyData();
       myData.setName("testName");
       myData.setNumber()
    
       Mockito.when(myRepository.findMyDataByNameAndNumber(
                Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010")).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(myData));
    }
    
    @Test
    void getMyData(){
        myServiceTest.getDataByNameAndNumber("testName", "10101010")
        
        Mockito.verify(myRepository, times(1))
                .findMyDataByNameAndNumber(Mockito.eq("testName"), Mockito.eq("10101010"));
    }
}
```

Thank you @marc for your suggestion in the comment :)