# Test class in spring dosn't work properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I would like to test my controller class. But I couldn't manage to run springBootTest class. My project written in spring boot. We are writing REST API using spring boot.
When I try to excute following test class. I still get following line from terminal.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;



/*
 *
 *  @A Sabirov Jakhongir
 *
 */


@SpringBootTest
@WebMvcTest
public class PrivilegesControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegesController privilegesController;


    @Test
    public void add() {
        assertThat(privilegesController).isNotNull();

    }
}
```

[image]

I put here all needed dependency for testing from my project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What might be cause of not working of test Class.

Comment: Hello, have you tried to launch a test without springBootTest.

Comment: You either use `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest` you don't use them both (looking at your test I would say remove the `@WebMvcTest`). The first is a full blown integration test, where as the second uses a small part of the context. So they basically exclude each other. Remove the dependencies for jUnit5, those are already included in the `spring-boot-starter-test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Junit5` and `@SpringBootTest` will load the full application, I had faced the same issue before, you can find details about the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63245021/3493829) and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63296026/3493829).

The solution for this is to use your test without `@SpringBootTest`.
The solution to your test class is as below.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PrivilegesControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private PrivilegesController privilegesController;


    @Test
    public void add() {
        assertThat(privilegesController).isNotNull();

    }
}
```

You can also use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` instead of `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` itself is annotated with `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)` so you don't need to add that.

Comment: Okay, but `@SpringBootTest` is not working with `Junit-5` so the above is the solution

Comment: It works perfectly fine with jUnit5 and as of Spring Boot 2.1 you don't need to add `@ExtendsWith` as it has been annotated itself.

Answer (score 1):

To test spring boot application is **creating** your controller, use `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and to test the **behavior or responsibility** of the controller is better to use `@WebMvcTest`. No need to annotate both the annotation to one class.

There are two cases to test the controller's responsibility.

1. With running Server
2. Without Server

For 1st Case, you can use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` to start a server with a random port.

For 2nd Case, use `@WebMvcTest` for testing the web layer.

All the test cases are written with the following signature:

```
@Test
public void test_Name() throws Exception {
//your test definition
}
```

You can also read the Official Documentation of Spring Boot https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Comment: In your case, you are testing the application whether the spring boot application is creating your controller or not. So, use `@SpringBootTest` annotation.