# Spring Boot Test fails to load application context with JUnit 5 for a custom integration test source set

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit, integration-testing

I'd like to start with some integration tests for my spring boot backend service. Therefore I added a gradle plugin that helps me adding the `integrationTest` source set.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "9.4.1"
    id("org.unbroken-dome.test-sets") version "3.0.1" // <<
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
}
...
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
...
testSets {
    create("integrationTest")
}
...
```

Then I started building my first test spec:

```kotlin
// TeamApiIntegrationTest.kt

package com.myapp.integrationtest.api

import com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [TeamRepository::class])
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
class TeamApiIntegrationTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val teamRepository: TeamRepository
) {
    @Test
    fun `should fetch a list of two teams where the current auth user is part of`() {
        assertThat(teamRepository).isNotNull
    }
}
```

The exception I receive is this one:

```
    Failed to resolve parameter [com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository teamRepository] in constructor [public com.myapp.integrationtest.api.TeamApiIntegrationTest(com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository)]: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository teamRepository] in constructor [public com.myapp.integrationtest.api.TeamApiIntegrationTest(com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository)]: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.userservice.repository.TeamRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
[...]
```

I understand the problem but don't know why it occurs since I am explictly "adding" `TeamRepository` to the `ContextConfiguration`.

*EDIT*:

```kotlin
// TeamRepository.kt
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository()
interface TeamRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Team, String> {
    fun findByName(name: String): List<Team?>
    fun findByUsers(user: User): List<Team?>
}
```

Comment: Please add the `TeamRepository` code here. Do you have spring-boot-starter-test dependency?

Comment: @Ice I added the information in question

Comment: @ExtendWith accepts array, so `@ExtendWith(value = [SpringExtension::class])` Do you have configuration for database in your tests? Like h2 or testcontainers?

Comment: @Ice I read since Spring Boot 2.1 `@ExtendWith` is not needed anymore. Also it works without an array eveywhere else I use it. Yeah I have a configuration for an embedded test database. I use all that in my unit tests. But starting with my integration test source set here nothing seems to work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `@SpringBootTest`.
`@SpringBootTest` will look for actual configuration with `Junit 5`.

I have faced the same issue earlier in java
You can find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63245021/3493829)